Data fetch from firestore isn't found from second collection
I have 2 collections in Firestore created : businesses and companies , from businesses it's fetching and from companies is saying data isn't found. I created a website using flutter and the user completes 2 widgets with details , from first widget the data is fetching , from second one it doesn't
this is the admin panel
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AdminPanel extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Admin Panel', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: _getCombinedData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          }

          final combinedData = snapshot.data ?? [];

          if (combinedData.isEmpty) {
            return Center(child: Text('No data found'));
          }

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: combinedData.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final data = combinedData[index];
              return BusinessCard(data: data);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Stream<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _getCombinedData() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('businesses')
        .snapshots()
        .switchMap((businessSnapshot) {
      final businesses = businessSnapshot.docs;
      
      return Rx.combineLatest(
        businesses.map((business) {
          final businessData = business.data();
          final businessId = business.id;
          
          return FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('companies')
              .doc(businessId)
              .snapshots()
              .map((companySnapshot) {
            final companyData = companySnapshot.data() ?? {};
            return {
              ...businessData,
              'businessId': businessId,
              'companyDetails': companyData,
            };
          });
        }),
        (List<Map<String, dynamic>> combinedData) => combinedData,
      );
    });
  }
}

class BusinessCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> data;

  const BusinessCard({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final businessData = data;
    final companyData = data['companyDetails'] as Map<String, dynamic>;

    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
      elevation: 4,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
      child: ExpansionTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
          child: Text(
            businessData['businessName']?[0] ?? '?',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(
          businessData['businessName'] ?? 'Unnamed Business',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
        ),
        subtitle: Text(businessData['category'] ?? 'No Category'),
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                _buildSectionTitle('Business Details'),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.business, 'Business Name', businessData['businessName']),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.category, 'Category', businessData['category']),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.email, 'Email', businessData['email']),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.phone, 'Phone', businessData['phoneNumber']),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.location_city, 'Localitate', businessData['localitate']),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.map, 'Judet', businessData['judet']),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                _buildSectionTitle('Company Details'),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.business, 'Company Name', companyData['companyName']),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.numbers, 'Registration Number', companyData['registrationNumber']),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.confirmation_number, 'CUI', companyData['cui']),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.person, 'Role', companyData['role']),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.phone, 'Company Phone', companyData['companyPhone']),
                _buildInfoRow(Icons.email, 'Company Email', companyData['companyEmail']),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSectionTitle(String title) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20,
          color: Colors.blue[800],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInfoRow(IconData icon, String label, String? value) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Icon(icon, size: 20, color: Colors.grey[600]),
          SizedBox(width: 8),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(label, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Text(value ?? 'N/A', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700])),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

For company details it shows only N/A

stream: _getCombinedData(),. DO NOT define the stream creation in the stream: parameter of the StreamBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the StreamBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg
